# change color of @drawable inside of an item

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, colors

I want to change the color of my @drawable inside an item. Here is my current code:

```
<item android:gravity="bottom|start"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:height="160dp"
    >
    <rotate
        android:pivotY="50%" android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="270" android:toDegrees="270"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_left_circle"
        />
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the XML you provided is not complete. I assume you're using `<layer-list>` , which creates LayerDrawable. You can cast your Drawable to LayerDrawable, then you can use `LayerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(Int)` to get the proper layer and tint the layer using `Drawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY)`. `Mode.MULTIPLY` will only work if the layer is white, if it's not I recommend using `Mode.SRC_OVER`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Drawable.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, Mode.MULTIPLY )`. This would set white pixels to red but I don't think it would affect the transparent pixels.

Comment: I have not only one item in my xml, and every item has another color. if i would use your code all items would have the same color.